# BootstrapのCSSを用いる際にclassを一括指定したい

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

現在、[オフィシャルサイト](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-example)の記述のような形でclassに値を設定しています:

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
    <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
  </div>
  ...
</form>
```

このとき、 `<form>`直下の`<div>`には常に`class="form-group"`を、また、その直下の`<input>`には常に`class="form-control"`を設定する必要があることがわかっている場合、これらをhtml/css側で(つまり、javascriptを使用せずに)一括して指定することは可能でしょうか？

以下は私の勝手なイメージですが、このようにcssで継承関係的なものが表せる方法があるのでは…と考えましたが見つけることができませんでした。

```html
form > div {
  parent: .form-group;
  ...(追加の指定)...;

  > input {
    parent: .form-control;
    ...(追加の指定)...;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Can a CSS class inherit one or more other classes? の回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1065476) にある通り、LESSのMixins機能で要望を満たせます。

所望のスタイルを設定する.lessファイルの内容は下記のようになるでしょう:

```
@import (less) "bootstrap.css";

form > div {
  .form-group;
  > input {
    .form-control;
  }
}
```

.htmlファイル側でこの.lessファイル及びless.jsファイルを認識させます:

```
...
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.0/less.min.js"></script>
  ...
</head>
...
```

この方法では、厳密にはjavascriptを用いていないとは言えませんが、.lessファイルを.cssファイルへ[事前に変換しておく](http://lesscss.org/#using-less-command-line-usage)ことも可能で、そうしておけば実行時にjavascriptは真に不要となります。

Answer (score 3):

ＣＳＳは、対応するＨＴＭＬのスタイルを指定するものですので、
ＨＴＭＬの構造をＣＳＳから変更することはできません。
（ＣＳＳでスクリプトを実行するようなものは例外）

ＨＴＭＬも静的に作成されるので、エディタのような編集段階でなんらかの変換を行うようなもので無い場合動的に変更する場合javascriptを使用せずに変更することはできません。
なので、
結論としては
javascriptを使わずにクラス指定がない状態から動的にクラス付けすることはできません。

Comment: javascriptを使用せずに、と記載した意図は、レイアウトの領域にjavascriptを踏み込ませたくない、また、そのようなコードを保守せざるを得ない状況にしたくない、ということでした。
質問を記載した後更に調べてみましたところ、同等のQ&A [Can a CSS class inherit one or more other classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065435/)を見つけ、この回答にあるLESSで希望を満たすことが出来ました。
後ほど自己回答として本件フォローアップ致します。